# Ruby on Rails app keeps crashing when pushing to heroku with no information in the logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, heroku

I'm trying to push my ruby on rails app to heroku, but every time I do, the app crashes after deploying. The logs also do not mention what is causing it to crash. When I try running heroku run rake db:migrate, I get an error saying:

Caused by:
Gem::LoadError: sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.

I have looked at many posts on here and did what many suggested of moving the sqlite3 gem to the development method in the gemfile and putting the pg gem in the production method in the gemfile. I then ran bundle install and tried pushing to heroku again but still ran into the same issue where the app would crash and I would not get any relevant feedback in the logs.

Here is my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.7', '>= 5.0.7.2'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'devise'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'sqlite3'

  #All from :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

#group :development do
#end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.21' # for Heroku deployment
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

And here is the errors I am getting when trying to run heroku run rake db:migrate:

```
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:176:in `rescue in spec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:173:in `spec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `instance_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:324:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/app/models/application_record.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `block in require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:150:in `exclusive'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:358:in `require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:512:in `load_missing_constant'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `const_missing'
/app/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `block in require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:150:in `exclusive'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:358:in `require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:512:in `load_missing_constant'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `const_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `const_get'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `block in constantize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `inject'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `constantize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:584:in `get'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:615:in `constantize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise.rb:320:in `get'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:83:in `to'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:78:in `modules'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:95:in `routes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:162:in `default_used_route'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise.rb:350:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise.rb:350:in `add_mapping'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:243:in `block in devise_for'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `devise_for'
/app/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:391:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:391:in `eval_block'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:373:in `draw'
/app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:77:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:119:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:360:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Gem::LoadError: sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:377:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `instance_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:324:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/app/models/application_record.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `block in require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:150:in `exclusive'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:358:in `require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:512:in `load_missing_constant'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `const_missing'
/app/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `block in require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:150:in `exclusive'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:358:in `require_or_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:512:in `load_missing_constant'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:203:in `const_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `const_get'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `block in constantize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `inject'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `constantize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:584:in `get'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:615:in `constantize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise.rb:320:in `get'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:83:in `to'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:78:in `modules'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:95:in `routes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:162:in `default_used_route'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise.rb:350:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise.rb:350:in `add_mapping'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:243:in `block in devise_for'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `devise_for'
/app/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:391:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:391:in `eval_block'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:373:in `draw'
/app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:77:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:119:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:360:in `exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm not sure what exactly the issue is because I know that heroku does not support sqlite, only postgres, but it's letting me deploy the app fine. It's just not allowing me to migrate my database to heroku. Does anyone have an idea as to why it would be doing this?

Comment: try removing the sqlite gem from your gem file as you dont need it anymore in production and check if you still get any errors related to sqlite

Comment: @yogeshmanjhi So I just tried removing the sqlite3 gem and seem to be getting the same errors I posted above unfortunately

Comment: Heroku wants your application to use postgresql. Adding gem pg will probally fix it.

Comment: did you remove the gem.lock and did bundle install locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `rails_12factor` gem that's not required anymore. To maintain [dev / prod parity](https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity) move `pg` gem out of production group and try to run the app successfully on local and re-deploy. Whatever is causing your app to use sqlite can be found this way and fixed for Heroku Deploy.